# Extended Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

Is there a closed expression for the following definite integral?

$$\int_{- \infty}^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{ax^2}{2}+bx^3+cx^4\right) \, dx;$$

$a,b,c$ are constants.

I know that one can perform a series expansion in the terms with $b$ and $c$, but I think this integral can be expressed in Terms of Special functions. Is there a Special technique to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- For $b=0$ and $c=0$, we have a simple [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), if *a* is positive.
- For $b=0$ and $c<0$, we have two analytic expressions in terms of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), depending on whether *a* is positive or negative.
- For $b=0$ and $c>0$, the integral diverges.
- For $b\neq0$ and $c=0$, the integral diverges.